# How to display a ListView in alphabetical order?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a XAML Listview.
In c#, I have my class with the properties "NomeRegione" of the class "Regioni".
I then created a list of Regioni:

```
List<Regioni> reg = new List<Regioni>
            {
                new Regioni
                {
                    NomeRegione="Valle d'Aosta"
                },

                new Regioni
                {
                    NomeRegione="Piemonte"
                },
```

I then grouped the elements so:

```
var gruppi = reg.GroupBy(x => x.NomeRegione.Substring(0,1));
Museum.Source = gruppi;
```

"Museum" is my CollectionViewSource.

How can I view my app, the elements of the ListView in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw in an `OrderBy`:

```
var gruppi = reg.OrderBy(x => x.NomeRegione).GroupBy(x => x.NomeRegione.Substring(0,1));
Museum.Source = gruppi;
```